# Processing Video as a string of images

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a project where part of it is processing a video as a batch of images. I found a snippet online which helped me process a batch of images(the one attached below)

```
string Img_seq[] = {"flying_plane"};

int size_of_Img_seq = sizeof(Img_seq) / sizeof(Img_seq[0]);
    imgpath = argv[1];
    if (argc >= 3)
    {
        TrackingResPath = argv[2];


    cout << "The image path is: " << imgpath << endl;
    int Seg_num = 1; //for OPE
    for (int j = 0; j < size_of_Img_seq; ++j)
    {
        folder = imgpath + Img_seq[j] + "/*.jpg";
        string imgInFormat, imgOutFormat, imgOutFormat1, imgOutFormat2; 
        ofstream outBB;
        imgInFormat = imgpath + Img_seq[j] + "/%05d.jpg";

        if (argc >= 3)
        {
            //add process here
        }
        }


        // get the total number of images in folder
        glob(folder, filenames);

        int Frames_per_seg = filenames.size(); // for OPE
        cout << "Frames_per_seg = " << Frames_per_seg << endl;

        for (int k = 1; k <= Seg_num; ++k)
        {
            sprintf(imgInPath, imgInFormat.c_str(), startFrame);// read image path
            sprintf(imgOutPath, imgOutFormat.c_str(), startFrame);
      }
```

I need to use this procedure to process a video from either a directory or from the webcam. I tried the one way which I've given below but it is spitting out errors

```
VideoCapture capture(videoFilename);
    if(!capture.isOpened()){
        cerr << "Unable to open video file:" << videoFilename << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while( (char)keyboard != 'q' && (char)keyboard != 27){
        if(!capture.read(frame)){
            cerr << "Unable to read next frame" << endl;
            cerr << "Exiting" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }}
        stringstream ss;
        rectangle(frame, cv::Point(10, 2), cv::Point(100, 20),
            cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
        ss << capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES);
        string Img_seq[] = ss.str();
        keyboard = waitKey( 30 );
```

The errors are basically because `Img_seq[]` is not linked properly between the above two codes.

Could anyone help me understand how I should proceed in using video for a batch processing logic.

Comment: Is this all in one file? Why is Img_seq[] global? At least put it in an anonymous namespace, better in a named namespace (this includes classes). Don't use `using namespace`, I assume `string` is `std::string` and `VideoCapture` is `cv::VideoCapture`. But - besides other dangers (std and cv DO have symbols with the same names), `using namespace` makes this really hard to read. And finally: what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: yes all of this is in one file, the whole thing is not really a function. string over here is under opencv not the std library. As far as I have seen the syntax of Videocapture is direct isint it?

Comment: The error is that initializer fails to determine the size of the string, I think this is because the logic used for batch processing is different. I need to know how do I change the batch processing logic so that I may use it for video sequencing